# Facebook website plugins

Tags: html, facebook, api, facebook-javascript-sdk

For adding Facebook page plugin I am using the following code

```
'<html>
   <head>
   <title>Your Website Title</title>
      <!-- You can use open graph tags to customize link previews.
      Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
       <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
      </head>
      <body>



 <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/TheDivert/" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/TheDivert/"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/TheDivert/">The Divert</a></blockquote></div></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

But the result is that only a hyperlink is created and the result shown on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin from where the code is taken is not shown. Could anyone find the problem with my code as I assume face books code will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <title>Your Website Title</title>
      <!-- You can use open graph tags to customize link previews.
      Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
      </head>
      <body>



 <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/TheDivert/" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/TheDivert/"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/TheDivert/">The Divert</a></blockquote></div></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Same code as before, except that you were missing:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

and the XFBML version number:

```
&version=v2.5
```

I figured this out by comparing your code against the code generated from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

I've tested this on a live server and it works, but if it doesn't, let me know.

*Sidenote: Remember to turn off Ghostery and/or other FB blocking browser extensions when testing.*

Comment: It did not work the code in the browser is the same as what you wrote but the code in is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin here http://pastebin.com/iVzxYmaS you can see it for yourself if you inspect the element.

Comment: And other peoples plugins are working so its not an issue of blocking @Optimae